# the menu button backgrounds are overridden by page image background, how do i prevent this?

Tags: html, css

after applying a background image to the body, the menu buttons backgrounds are overridden as seen below. i want the menu buttons to preserve their visibility.

link to image is below
http://s11.postimage.org/4ndla4hxf/111111111.jpg

```
/********markup********/

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/modernizr-1.7.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="page">
        <header>
            <div id="title">
                <h1>My MVC Application</h1>
            </div>
            <div id="logindisplay">
                @Html.Partial("_LogOnPartial")
            </div>
            <nav>
                <ul id="menu">
                    <li >@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>
        <section id="main">
            @RenderBody()
        </section>
        <footer>
        </footer>
    </div>
</body>
</html>

/*******body***********/

body
{

    font-size: .85em;
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS" , Verdana, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;

  background-image:url('/Content/bw.jpg');


}

/*******menu**********/

#menu
{


        position:relative;
    float:left;
    clear:left;
    margin-right:50px;

}

#menu li
{

    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0px;
    display: block;     
        width:150px;
    overflow:visible;

}

#menu li a
{
        overflow:visible;
        background: rgba(0,0,0,0.2); 
        text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px white;
        color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 13px;
    display: block;
    font-family: arial;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #eee;
    padding:10px 20px 10px;
    margin: 5px;
    font-weight: bold;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s linear;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s linear;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s linear;
    -ms-transition: all 0.2s linear;
    transition: all 0.2s linear;


    -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);  
    -moz-box-shadow: 2px 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);  
    box-shadow: 2px 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);  

    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;  
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;  
    border-radius: 3px;  

}



#menu li a:hover
{
    opacity: 1;
    color:White;
    background:#FF00D0  ;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #ffffff;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);  
    -moz-transform: scale(1.2);  
    -ms-transform: scale(1.2);   
    -o-transform: scale(1.2);   
    transform: scale(1.2); 

}


#menu li a:active {  
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);  
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);  
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);  
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);  
}
```

Comment: what browser? can you post a working example, eg. in jsfiddle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure the buttons don't just look grey when there's no background image as opacity is so low.

When you then apply the background image you cant see the buttons background colour as the the opacity is so low and the background colour so strong.

Temporarily update `#menu li a` and see if the problem still exists.

```
    background: #FF0000;
```

Example here: http://benjaminhopkins.co.uk/BGLostExample.html

Comment: you're correct, but can I fix the problem without having to change the background of the buttons?

Comment: You will have to tweak the `background` value to make them show but should be easy enough. If you don't need them have any opacity change the background to `#CCC` or if you do try `rgba(210,210,210,0.8)`